# Combinatorics: Maximum number of triangles

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, triangles

**[Question:]**

There are three coplanar parallel lines. If any $p$ points are taken on each of the lines, the maximum number of triangles with vertices on these points is

**[The solution given is:]**

Select any three points from total $3p$ points, which can be done $^{3p}C_3​$ ways.

But this also includes selection of three collinear points.

Now three collinear points from each straight line can be selected in $^pC_3$​ ways.

Then the number of triangles is $^{3p}C_3​−3(^pC_3)​=p^2(4p−3)$.

---

The part I don't understand is would it not be possible for $3$ points selected form $3$ different lines to be collinear?

We have accounted for collinear points present on the same line through $3(^pC_3)$ but not the case where they are present on different lines.

Comment: The problem asks for the $\textit {maximum}$ number.  You are right in saying that some configurations yield fewer.

Comment: that makes sense